# Stop a if loop with a command

Tags: java

So basically i am trying to make two commands called !on and !off and when the user types in !on it will start this infinite for loop and once the user types !off the infinite for loop will stop.
I have already tried many methods but it doesn't work such as another for loop such as:

```
if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("!on"){
    for(int i=0; i<10){
*random code*
}
}
if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("!off"){
i = 10;
}
```

i have also tried boolean but the code won't execute util the infinite loop is over.

BEFORE YOU COMMENT PLEASE READ:
i want this to infinite loop but my question is if the user types !off is it possible to stop the infinite loop from looping.

basically what i'm trying to ask if it's possible to break out of a infinite loop

Comment: How are you getting `userInput`? Why not loop until `userInput` is not `!off` with a `while` loop?

Comment: There is no such thing as an `if` loop. There is a `for` loop, and a `while` loop. What you want to do is `while (condition is true) { do something }`

Comment: Please consider learning the basics of Java before posting questions here, you can find many materials online if you search

Comment: first check i scope in for loop you make it local so its not possible to access i out side this for loop. your code is compile time error.                   wrong for loop syntex  you have not place semicolumn after i<10;

Comment: Good news~! I found a working example of what you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463968/how-to-make-a-while-to-run-until-scanner-get-input

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem here is in your for loop.

Your for loop `for(int i=0; i<10)`triggers an infinite loop because the variable i is not being incremented, and will stay under 10 infinitely.

Replacing the for loop with `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)` and see if executing the loop still results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, i know it's posting a infinite loop. I want it to be infinite. But my question is when the user type a command like !off is there any possible way to stop the command from looping

Answer (score 0):

First, this is logically and syntactically nonsense. Don't do this.

```
if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("!on"){
    for(int i=0; i<10){
        *random code*
    }
}

if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("!off"){
    i = 10;
}
```

What you are looking for is probably something closer to this:

```
if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("!on"){
    while(true){ //proper way to start an infinite loop
        userinput = /* read user input with your preferred method */;
        if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("!off"){
            break; //break ends the closest loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make use of multithreading. Have one thread running your infinite loop and the other grabbing user input to stop the thread running the loop.

Basics of Multithreading: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-java/

Request thread stop: https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2015/12/06/understanding-thread-interruption-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can break out of a loop by checking a variable:

```
static volatile boolean stopLoop = false;
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true)  {
            String input = System.console().readLine();
            if (input.equals("!off")) {
                stopLoop = true;
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

    while (!stopLoop) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is you want a loop that keeps going until a certain condition is met. Consider a `while` loop such as below written in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String userInput = "!on";

    while (isUserInputOn(userInput)) {
         System.out.println("Do stuff");
         userInput = getUserInput(); // Then something changes the state of userInput
    }
}

private static boolean isUserInputOn(String userInput) {
    return "!on".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput);
}

private static String getUserInput() {
    double random = Math.random() * 10D;

    if(random > 5) {
        return "!on";
    } else {
        return "!off";
    }    
}
```

Note that the method `getUserInput()` checks for changes in `userInput` and this needs to be written accroding to your business logic as currently it's using ramdom double number.